# Unable to get output from remote Device using Net::SSH2

Tags: perl, ssh, blocking

I am trying to connect to a remote device through Net::SSH2. If I am using $channel->blocking(0) method, then I am not getting any output from the device even if the connection and authentication is successful. If I dont use $channel->blocking(0), then I am getting the output but the prompt keeps on blinking, in the sense the the program gets stuck.

**Code**

```
use Net::SSH2;
use strict;

$ssh = Net::SSH2->new()

$ssh->connect('xx.xx.xx.xx'))

$ssh->auth(username => 'xxxx', password => 'xxxx'))

my  $channel = $ssh->channel() or do { print" [LOG ERROR]: Failed to create channel. Exiting ...\n"};

$channel->blocking(0);

$channel->shell() ;

print $channel "show status \n";

while(<$channel>)
  {
     print $_;
  }

$channel->close(); 

$ssh->disconnect();
```

can somebody please help.

Comment: If you use `shell` then you have to "talk" to the remote shell. It doesn't get stuck, it is just there waiting for you to enter more commands.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [debug](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH2#debug-(-state-)) could help you by troubleshooting. If there is no particular reason why you are using `shell` try to replace it by `exec`. You could adopt this [example](https://github.com/rkitover/net-ssh2/blob/master/example/read.pl#L43).

`use warnings` is also always useful.

Comment: Using exec I can execute only one command. As per my requirement I need to read multiple commands. Can you please help.

Comment: Unfortunately no, because I've got an [issue](https://github.com/Juniper/netconf-perl/issues/29) related to perl Net::SS2 as well and switched to [ncclient](https://github.com/ncclient/ncclient)